# ajaxStop() is firing but ajaxStart() doesn't

Tags: jquery, ajax

Every time I call my servlet by clicking a button, I receive the ajaxStop() message, but it doesn't work for ajaxStart() and I don't know why. Here is my code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#continue").click(function () {
            var period = $("#period").val();
            var year = $("#year").val();
            var dataString = {"period": period, "year": year};
             $.ajax({
                url: 'GenerateButtons',
                data: dataString,
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#uploadFileButtons').html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            console.log("ajaxStart");
        }).ajaxStop(function(){
           console.log("ajaxStop");
        });
 });
```

Im using Firefox and NetBeans for my web application by the way.

**[Update edit]**
I tested it in a separated project and it works fine. After doing that, I realized that one of the ajax code is getting invoked by something weird like this. It triggers the ajaxStop() but not the ajaxStart() . So I have to tell the dude who did this that he has to fix it. In any case, it seems that ajaxStop/ajaxStart has to be called by a jQuery event to get both triggered correctly.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var p = document.getElementById("menssage").innerHTML;

    if (p === "This period is already processed") {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ShowDiffServlet',
            data: dataString,
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#tabla').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
        $("#continue").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#warningReprocess").show(1000);
    }
    if (p === "File was successfully uploaded!") {
        var dataString;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ShowDiffServlet',
            data: dataString,
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
        $("#continue").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#tableTitle").html("<hr><h1>Diff table</h1>");
    }

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        console.log("Starting loader");
        $loader.addClass("loading");
    }).ajaxStop(function(){
       console.log("Stopping loader");
       $loader.removeClass("loading");
    });
});
```

Comment: Any error logged in the console?

Comment: Nope, just the ajaxStop event message.

Comment: Your unaltered code works fine for me: https://codepen.io/skunkbad/pen/rzKQzy

Comment: It was my fault, I posted something that actually works, but not that weird and problematic code that is in the project. Thanks for your answer.